# Distance between two parallel Hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Currently studying hyperplanes, and trying to understand the derivation on these slides:

http://webdoc.nyumc.org/nyumc/files/chibi/user-content/Final.pdf

check page 36. The third equation is: $\vec{w} \cdot \vec{x}_2+b_2 = 0$. In my opinion, this should be $t\vec{w}\cdot\vec{x}_2+b_2 = 0$, or at least the entire equation should still be valid when using $t\vec{w}$ instead of $\vec{w}$. $t\vec{w}$ is still a vector characterizing the second hyperplane, by being perpendicular to it. However, when using $t\vec{w}$ one ends up with a complete different derivation. What is wrong with my train of thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\vec{w} \cdot \vec{x}_2 + b_2 = 0$ says that $\vec{x}_2$ is in the second plane, the one that the left hand side of the slide says is characterized by $\vec{w} \cdot \vec{x} + b_2 = 0$.

$t \vec{w} \cdot \vec{x}_2 + b_2 = 0$ would say that $t\vec{x}_2$ is in the second plane, which it isn't (unless $t = 1$).

Answer (score 0):

Is that $t\vec{w}\cdot\vec{x}_2+tb_2 = 0$ that you would like to start with? The hyperplane equation would then remain the same for a point $\vec x_2 $  is contained in the hyperplane.